# How do I insert a space after a character in a textbox, depending on the total characters entered, JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add a space in a textbox depending on the total characters entered by the user.

For example if the user entered 'LU33RT' on blur I'd like it to display 'LU3 3RT'. The rule that I'm looking to incorporate is by counting 3 characters in from the right then add a space.

`$('#postcode').blur(...`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

---

My Solution, Although it's basic:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#postcode').blur(function(){
        if(($(this).val().length == 6) && (/\S/)){
           var myString = $(this).val().slice(0, 3);
           var myString2 = $(this).val().slice(-3);
           $(this).val(myString + ' ' + myString2);
        }else{ 
            document.write('OOPS!');}
    }); 
});
```

Comment: 'LU33RTFOO' should be 'LU3 3RT FOO'?

Comment: @Jacques - 'LU33RTFOO' should become 'LU33RT FOO'

Comment: ...and should have its post mis-delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RegExp to replace the last 3 characters with a space plus the same 3 characters:

```
$('#postcode').blur(function(){
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/...$/, ' $&'));
});
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/PJMDp/1/

If you really must count 3 characters, you should use `slice`, not `substring`:

```
$('#postcode').blur(function(){
  var postcode = $(this), val = postcode.val();
  if(val.length > 3)
    postcode.val(val.slice(0, -3)+' '+val.slice(-3));
});
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/PJMDp/2/

Comment: What is `&& (/\S/)` for? `/\S/` is a RegExp object which is interpreted as `true`, so `($(this).val().length == 6) && (/\S/)` is equivalent to `$(this).val().length == 6`.

Comment: The regex expression is to check for NO whitespaces/tabs/line breaks etc. The reason I need this is to make sure the user enters 6 characters excluding any whitespaces...if the both conditions are not met, this means 6+ characters have been returned, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#postcode').blur(function()
{
    $(this).val( $(this).val().substring( 0, -3 ) + ' ' + $(this).val().substring( -3 ));
}
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" value="<%=Server.HTMLEncode(postcode)%>" />

Comment: for some reason the code isnt working...I added the missing bracket for the .blur function...help

Comment: I've got it kind of working but it adds a space at the very begining of the string...not 3 character from the right??

Comment: This is quite a bit less elegant than using a regular expression, it's inefficient for calling `$(this)` and `.val()` unnecessarily many times, and it should be `slice`, not `substring`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a regex replace:

```
$('#postcode').blur(function() {
     var str = $(this).val();

     // I assume that since the example had 6 characters that this was the min you were looking for
     if(str.length >= 6) {
         $(this).val(str.replace(/.{3}$/, " $&"));
     }
});
```

Comment: this is for a textbox where user enter postcode...it can be LU3 3RT or SW12 2BA ...I think the best approach is just counting 3 characters in from the right then adding a space. I tried your code & for some reason it's not working...I added the closing bracket for the .blur(function(){...});

Comment: Nasir, the regular expression is looking for the last 3 characters at the end of the string (dot = any character, {n} means n instances of the previous expression, $ = anchored at the end of the string). If you need to ignore strings that already have a space at the fourth-to-last location, that's a slight adjustment, but can be done.

Comment: Oh, beat me to it. Well, the `.{3}` takes more space than `...`, but the reason this doesn't work is you accidentally wrote `str` rather than `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like [MAsked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)?

I think it may be of use if properly adapted.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I'd say to make sure your postcode is always correctly formatted, without having to worry about the length of the postcode, do the following:

```
$("#postcode").bind("blur", function(){
    var postcode_fix = $(this).val().toUpperCase().replace(/ /g,'');
    postcode_fix = postcode_fix.slice(0, -3)+' '+postcode_fix.slice(-3);
    $(this).val(postcode_fix);
});
```